# Why won't my jQuery UI modal dialog close in Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-9, jquery-ui-dialog

I am working on an ASP.NET application in which I'm using several jQuery UI modal dialogs. They all work properly in Chrome and Firefox, but one of them will not close when I click the "X" in Internet Explorer 9. Clicking the "X" just makes this particular dialog "non-modal", in other words the greyed-out background goes away and I can interact with the form underneath, but the dialog itself doesn't close.

Here's the code that's creating the dialog, and the function which opens it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      //Setup dialog
      $("#reinstatementForms").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 500,
        height: "auto",
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        open: function (event, ui) { $(this).css("display", "block"); },
        close: function (event, ui) { $('body').find('#reinstatementForms').remove(); }
      });
    });

    function ShowReinstatementForms() {
      $(#reinstatementForms").dialog("open");
      return false;
    }
</script>
```

Here's the HTML/ASPX markup (abbreviated):

```
<div id="reinstatementForms" title="Reinstatement Forms Required" class="modalDialog" style="display: none;">
  <h2 style="padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;">Reinstatement Forms Are Required</h2>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....
  </p>
</div>
```

I'm triggering this particular dialog from code behind (C#) based on a condition being true:

```
if (reinstatementForms)
{
  string dialogScript = "ShowReinstatementForms()";
  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "ShowReinstatementForms", dialogScript, true);
}
```

Any clues how to make this work properly in IE? Again, my other modals (which are being called/triggered in different ways) work fine in IE (IE 9 - I don't have access to any other version at the moment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it will work in FF or chrome.   **$(#reinstatementForms").dialog("open");** is missing ". It should be **$("#reinstatementForms").dialog("open");**

Good luck!